# Magento 2.3 Change position of "Review & payments" section on checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.3

I want to change the position of the highlighted section at the "review & payments" section within the checkout so the billing address is before the payment methods. I've created an image to visualize it a bit.

[image: Wanted changes to the positions]

I've already checked a few other posts about this but i cant find the `billing.phtml` file anywhere inside the `vendor/magento/module_checkout` folder.

---

**UPDATE**
After a ton of research i believe the sort order should be inside the `checkout_index_index.xml` file which is located under `vendor/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout` but im unable to find the reference to the billing address.